# iRedmail damaged my LAMP installation

Tags: ubuntu, email, vps

I have Ubuntu Server based VPS, which have LAMP installed.
It have Apache, MySQL, PHPMyAdmin, PHP etc. and everything is in use for my website.
I installed iRedmail, and now my website can't be accessed anymore, just redirects to mydomain.com/mail, and my Webmin is also down.

I tried to remove it so I followed article here: http://www.iredmail.org/forum/topic333-iredmail-support-faq-how-to-uninstall-iredmail.html
It seems removed, I also manually uninstalled Postfix. 
Removed everything non default from `/var/apache2/sites-enabled`
And still doesn't work as before! It still redirects to /mail directory and Webmin is down...

**EDIT: Just fixed redirection problem by deleting previously unnoticed index.html. But my Webmin doesn't work, even after re-installation and reboot.**

I also checked out mine website /var/www/ index.php file and .htaccess file. There is no redirection commands.

I don't want to fresh install everything, so what I need to do? I'm so pissed off, why it had to touch my Apache and Webmin installation? iRedmail is garbage.

Comment: And exactly how did you _install_ it?

Comment: wget https://bitbucket.org/zhb/iredmail/downloads/iRedMail-0.8.5.tar.bz2 | Then # bash iRedMail.sh
Installation has started and that's it. I followed instructions http://www.iredmail.org/install_iredmail_on_ubuntu.html#start_installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed both problems.

Redirection problem is fixed by deleting index.html or by removing the meta refresh tag in it.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=mail/">
```

and by entering few commands in terminal

```
# rm /etc/apache2/conf.d/roundcubemail.conf
# rm /etc/apache2/conf.d/cluebringer.conf
```

**Restart Apache:**

```
# sudo service apache2 restart
```

Source for commands: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-remove-iredmail

For Webmin and few other network apps, it was problem with IP tables. iRedmail was messed up something there, so I followed this article and everything is back to normal:

```
# sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
# sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
# sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
# sudo iptables -F
# sudo iptables -X
```

Source: http://www.prash-babu.com/2008/10/how-to-flush-or-remove-all-iptables.html